# Tsung not working with JabberHttpBind

Tags: tsung

I'm using tsung to test BOSH with openfire and jabberd2.
I'm able to test openfire with tsung.
But for jabberd2+JabberHttpBind, the authentication itself does not happen.

Any clues or tricks to troubleshoot will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.